# How to create Facades in Laravel 5.0 without using composer?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

Thanks to all in advance.

I am trying to create Facades for my custom and common functions in laravel 5.0 also I don`t want to create controller for that so I am using Facades.

I have tried almost every tutorial but it do not help me.

Please help me to create facade without using Composer in Laravel 5.0.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you're creating a class of facade like this:

```
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class SomeFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'someService';
    }
}
```

then You create a service class that hold your functionalities:

```
namespace App\Services;

class SomeService { ... }
```

Finally you have to register it and set an alias (not required) for it:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProivider extends ServiceProvider
{
    (...)
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('someService', function () {
            return new \App\Services\SomeService();
        });
        $this->app->alias('SomeServiceFacade', \App\Facades\SomeFacade::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can call your methods from `SomeService` with:

```
SomeServiceFacade::someMethhod();
```

or

```
app('someService')->someMethhod();
```

Comment: If you don`t mind can you please explain it more with header files/

Comment: With 'header files' you mean what?

Comment: I mean, please explain this example with full code including namespaces.

Comment: OK. I've  reedit my entry with namespaces. Of course you can change then for what you what.

Comment: FatalErrorException in AccountController.php line 33:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SomeServiceFacade' not found
I get this error back

Comment: If you're inside the controller you have to give: `\` before `\SomeServiceFacade` or add `use SomeServiceFacade` in the header of controller class.

Comment: This is why i am using Facade because I don`t want to use "use" or include any header file.

Comment: Again this error
FatalErrorException in AccountController.php line 33:
Class 'SomeServiceFacade' not found

Comment: If  alias loader not working for some reason, try to use this: `app('someService')->someMethhod();` <- it's the same. Maybe your service provider wasn't lunched

Comment: This also not working. "Class someService does not exist"

Comment: Does it need to add new service to `config/app.php` ?